# I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8775/api/n1/nkl/application1": PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, resttemplate, truststore

We are getting below mentioned exception while making a microservice call using REST template in springBoot.
I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8775/api/n1/nkl/app1": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

We are using SSL. We have a single certificate which we should be used for both applications.We are able to make microservice call successfully after disabling the SSL. However, once we enable it, we are getting above mentioned exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your application doesn't trust in the certificate of the service. You need to create an SSLContext which is configured to use the truststore that contains the certificate and then use it to configure the HttpClient used by RestTemplate.